# Javers demo project broken?

Tags: javers

I just started evaluating Javers and downloaded the organization-structure demo provided on the Javers homepage. The `organization-structure-sql` project does not seem to correct identify changes.

1. `git clone https://github.com/javers/organization-structure.git`
2. Imported project into Intellij
3. An SqlApplication as Spring Boot project
4. The project starts up several rest endpoints to make updates to an H2 database and to test the Javers API with those changes

   a) localhost:8080/view/person/0

   ```
   {
       "id": 0,
       "firstName": "Frodo",
       "lastName": "Baggins",
       "sex": "MALE",
       "salary": 9000,
       "position": "DEVELOPER"
   }
   ```

   b) localhost:8080/audit/test

   makes changes to Person/0 above

   c) localhost:8080/view/person/0

   shows the audit/test endpoint updated salary from 9000->1234:

   ```
   {
       "id": 0,
       "firstName": "Frodo",
       "lastName": "Baggins",
       "sex": "MALE",
       "salary": 1234,
       "position": "DEVELOPER"
   }
   ```

   d) localhost:8080/audit/person/0

   []
   expected: output that would show the update made to person/0

   Also, the PUT endpoint doesn't seem to work:

   e) `PUT localhost:8080/audit/person/0`

   ```
   {
       "id": 0,
       "firstName": "Frodo",
       "lastName": "Baggins",
       "sex": "MALE",
       "salary": 10000,
       "position": "DEVELOPER"
   }
   ```

   f) localhost:8080/view/person/0

   ```
   {
       "id": 0,
   "firstName": "Frodo",
   "lastName": "Baggins",
   "sex": "MALE",
   "salary": 1234,
   "position": "DEVELOPER"
   ```

   }

This simple demo not working doesn't inspire much confidence with using Javers.

Does anyone how to get this demo working?

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Explicitly state your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some fixes and now it should work better, but please note that `organization-structure` is just a toy project and not a part of official Javers documentation.